# Z values way too large compared to x and y in reconstruction

Tags: graphics, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

I reconstruct x,y,z from disparity using  triangulation formula .My problem is that x,y, and z  values are in very different orders .For eg order of x is like 0.001 and similar for y but z is in the order of 10 .Because of this I see a straight line instead of seeing a face .Is there any way I could apply some transform preserving the structure of face but getting a better reconstruction.

EDITED: here is a sample L image and the disparity map ( normalized to 0-255 for visualization not the true values).My point of giving this is to show that disparity comes out fairly decently.
[image: OriginalLeftImage]

[image: DisparityImage]

Comment: Besides dividing the Z values by 10? I think you'd have to explain to us why the data look the way they do.

Comment: I have no answer, but I found some more context for the question here: http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/indria/project/CSE576finalproject/finalproject/0-paper.html

Comment: @Ernest :-I am not sure what the reason is .It could be that to get L and R images we crop portions of bigger L and R images.Apart from that I am not sure why tht happens .For x and y though we use u and v where u = X- middleColumn.Isnt dividing by 10 going to squash the depth? Here are formulas I use : http://www.ptgrey.com/support/kb/index.asp?a=4&q=63

Comment: @e.James:-Thanks.. thats the page I referenced for getting the formula too.

Comment: @Manish: From the disparity map you posted, it looks like the 3D reconstruction should be pretty simple. Isn't it equivalent to a simple elevation map at this point? Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @e.James :- I thought so too ...the thing is if I zoom in and out of the reconstruction I see that a face is thr but there seems to be something fishy going on with the coordinates and the ranges they fall in ...also i am not sure abt what you meant by elevation map .If I just use the x and y as is and only put in z in the 3d point cloud it gives a decent result but my guess is that x, y also depend on disparity as the website points out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are solving for the fundamental matrix using point correspondences between the left and right images, this is the expected result. Because the fundamental matrix is rank-deficient, it is only defined up to a scale factor. If you define everything in terms of pixel units, there is no way to reconstruct the scene in real-world units.

Solving this requires an additional piece of information: the relationship between a pair of corresponding points in a three-dimensional coordinate frame. For a stereo system, this is most often the *baseline*, the distance between the left and right camera centers.

Comment: @Michael : i do not use anything related to fundamental matrix(atleast not knowingly) .For finding disparity I use OpenCV's matching function.For depth recovery I use z= Focal length*Baseline/Disparity .Here focal length is in pixels (coz I use the matlab tutorial and that says answer is in pixels).Disparity is in pixels and Baseline I enter is in metres so Z is effectively in metres then.

Comment: @Manish: If you're already multiplying by the baseline, then this is not the problem. Most likely this is related to your initial guess: processing a small region of interest in a larger image. Are you calibrating the camera using the full resolution image or only the region of interest?

Comment: @Michael Koval:- Till now I calibrated the camera using the whole image but only used a part of it as L and R images.I think this might be causing the error .Is this what you are pointing too?

Comment: @Manish: That might be the problem. If you are using OpenCV's camera calibration functions, you will need to modify the intrinsic matrix to adjust for the position of the ROI. The focal length (`f_x` and `f_y`) should be the same, but the image center (`c_x` and `c_y`) need to be shifted.

Comment: @Michael Koval : I do not use opencv's calibration function .I do the calibration in matlab using this (http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) which gives me the focal length and baseline which is really all I need to get the z .

Comment: @Manish: I have never used the Caltech calibration toolbox, but everything you're doing sounds correct. What focal length and baseline does the calibration give you?

Comment: @Michael Koval : Focal length comes around 1640 pixels and baseline is around .12 mts.